# SQL WHERE clause: sort by date for string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string, date

I have a column in my database table that holds dates in the format (mmm-yy) Ex: Aug-13. I'm trying to select all dates after Jun-12. The problem is the column is a string so when I say WHERE column > 'Jun-12' it gives me values that are alphabetically greater than Jun-12 such as May-12, which is not what i want. Any thoughts on how to go about this?

Comment: Stop using a string to hold dates and use a proper date format field that you then format to whatever string you want when you display it

Comment: Stop storing dates as strings

Comment: Use [str-to-date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: If the date is stored as a timestamp you can query for a date via WHERE column LIKE '06-12%' and then format to a string before outputting the contents of the column to the browser.

Comment: I can't fault the question, as there's situations where you inherit databases like this, unfortunately.  As for how to fix this, try doing a cast on your date field in your select, and do the comparison as so:  where date > '06/01/2013'

Comment: If you can't change the type, can you at least change the format? The [ISO date format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso_date) would allow you to do sorting and comparison on date-strings.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation you'll should be able to convert to a date and then filter as required, the below code should give you a guide,

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE CAST('01-' + column AS DATETIME) > '01-JUN-12'
```

Comment: Sure.

SELECT *, SUM(COST_BUDGET) Total_Budget,SUM(BURDENED_COST_TO_DATE) Total_Expenses, SUM(BURDENED_COST_PA_PERIOD) Monthly_Expenses
FROM Lab
WHERE CAST('01' + PA_PERIOD_NAME AS DATETIME) > '01-JUN-12'
GROUP BY PA_PERIOD_NAME
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(PA_PERIOD_NAME, '%M-%Y ')  ASC

Comment: what does SELECT * FROM Lab WHERE CAST('01' + PA_PERIOD_NAME AS DATETIME) > '01-JUN-12' get you?

Comment: And what does the below get you?
SELECT * 
FROM Lab 
WHERE CAST('01' + PA_PERIOD_NAME AS DATETIME) > '01-JUN-12'
GROUP BY '01' + PA_PERIOD_NAME 
ORDER BY CAST('01' + PA_PERIOD_NAME AS DATETIME) ASC

Comment: They all return nothing. mysqli_num_rows gives my nothing.

Comment: Ah, try with a Greater than or equal to (>=), this would explain the issue if you only have data for Jun-12 though. Outside that try runninv just the Select From and checking your getting data and then adding the elements one at a time, firat the order by then the where

Comment: I appreciate all the help you are giving me rhollyer. I have data from 2001-2013 and they are all working when when the CAST part is removed. Working just just Select From and working with Select From Where Order with the CAST removed. Ofcourse I have the same problem when I am getting only the alphabetically values greater than Jun-12

Comment: Think ive spotted it, try '01-' instead of the '01'

Answer (score 1):

Store dates as dates, not strings. That's the recommended way of doing it and I recommend changing your code accordingly.

In this case, you could use [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to compare the dates on the fly:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column > STR_TO_DATE('Jun-12','%m-%y');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ideally yeah, dates should be stored as dates, unfortunately there's only so much you can do if you inherit a database with the dates already set up like this, where changing the formatting breaks all sorts of other stuff.

Comment: @user2366842: hence the `STR_TO_DATE` suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys but the above solution did not work for me. I also tried: WHERE STR_TO_DATE(PA_PERIOD_NAME, '%M-%Y') > 'Jun-12' but that didn't work either. I know the STR_TO_DATE function works because I have ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(PA_PERIOD_NAME, '%M-%Y ')  ASC
which works fine.

Comment: @AshvicGodinho: It's case-sensntive. `%M` is not the same as `%m`.

Comment: Sorry still not working. My ORDER BY clause has %M and its working fine though.

Comment: @AshvicGodinho: What's the exact query you're running and the error/output you're getting?